# Java: pattern matcher method returns wrong result

Tags: java, regex

I have tried really hard to understand this, but I just don't get it.
 I don't understand why the start() method returns "456" after the group() method returns "34".

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("ab34ef");
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.print(m.start()+m.group());  // output: 01234456
}
```

Comment: what would you expect and why?

Comment: Because you still loop three more times after that?  How is supposed to know if there are any more groups if it doesn't check the rest of the input?

Comment: For clarity, the `start()` method *doesn't* return `"456"`.  It returns `4`, then `5`, then `6` on three respective calls.

Comment: Hi, thanks for these responses. Here is my confusion... it found "34" in positions 2 and 3, and I would have expected it to then finish the search in postions 4 and 5. 
But it prints 4, 5 and 6. Why 6?

Comment: Because position 6 is the end of the string, and `"\\d*"` means "zero or more digits", which matches the zero digits at the end of the string, immediately following the f.

Answer (score 1):

## [Regex explained](https://regex101.com/r/ubMdzV/1/)

Your regex finds 0 length items,which adds a lot of matches of 0 length.

## Explained

As the output is all on 1 line I split it to make it more readable.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("ab34ef");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("start:%s end:%s text:'%s'%n", m.start(), m.end(), m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
start:0 end:0 text:''
start:1 end:1 text:''
start:2 end:4 text:'34'
start:4 end:4 text:''
start:5 end:5 text:''
start:6 end:6 text:''
```

This matches your output of `01234456`:

- 0, 1 and 2 are all group starts
- 34 is the match text
- 4, 5 and 6 are all group starts